# Converting geometry from bounds to Polygon using GeoPandas

Tags: python, polygon, geopandas

I have a GeoPandas DataFrame with bounds geometry.

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({
                        'id': [0, 1],
                        'b': [((40.6494140625, -86.7919921875), (40.69335937...)), 
                              ((39.55078125, -93.8232421875), (39.5947265625...))]
                      })

gdf['b'][0]

Bounds(sw=SouthWest(lat=32.8271484375, lon=-96.8115234375), ne=NorthEast(lat=32.87109375, lon=-96.767578125))

print(type(gdf['b'][0]))

<class 'geolib.geohash.Bounds'>
```

How do I turn `Bounds` into `Polygon` geometry type?

Like,

```
Polygon((40.6494140625, -86.7919921875), (40.69335937...))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [shapely box](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#shapely.geometry.box)

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import box
lines = gpd.read_file("lines.shp")  
# total bounds of the shapefile       
xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax =  lines.total_bounds
print(xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax)
202611.93416148185 88948.08685124904 203905.81262856247 90209.61835665265
# convert to polygon
geom =box(*lines.total_bounds)
print(geom)
POLYGON ((203905.8126285625 88948.08685124904, 203905.8126285625 90209.61835665265, 202611.9341614819 90209.61835665265, 202611.9341614819 88948.08685124904, 203905.8126285625 88948.08685124904))
```

The shapefile and the total_bounds polygon:

[image]