# Bounds of shapefile to WKT - Geopandas

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas, extents

I have a `shp` that I have improted in Python with `geopandas`. I need to extract the bounding box as a WKT to be use in another step of my code. I know how to get to the bbox but I am stuck in convertign that into WKT format. I could write a work-around but I am looking for a more direct or native way if it exists. Any idea how to achive this? Below an example code

```
import geopandas as gpd

# 1. import shp
shp = gpd.read_file('your.shp')

# 2.  Extract bounds
bbox = shp.bounds

# 3. Convert bbox to WKT
?
```

Comment: Duplicate of    [Convert geometry from bounds to Polygon - GeoPandas](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/439832/2581)

Comment: My bad for not finding it before posting. Thanks for pointing it out.